# how to get a div of an other page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dynamic-content

I have made the content of `Index.html` dynamic by using `JQuery`

inside index I have

```
        <div id="main">
        </div>
```

and I have script to load the content:-

```
function LoadPage(url) {
    var req = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        try {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            req = false;
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                req = false;
            }
        }
    }
    var element = document.getElementById("main");
    if (!element) {
        alert("Bad id " +
         "passed to clientSideInclude." +
         "You need a div or span element " +
         "with this id in your page.");
        return;
    }
    if (req) {
        req.open('GET', url, false);
        req.send(null);
        element.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    } else {
        element.innerHTML =
       "Sorry, your browser does not support " +
          "XMLHTTPRequest objects. This page requires " +
          "Internet Explorer 5 or better for Windows, " +
          "or Firefox for any system, or Safari. Other " +
          "compatible browsers may also exist.";
    }
}
```

so I can use it as following `<a href="#" onclick="LoadPage('home.html')" title="Home">`

now the problem is if I loaded `Home.html` and home.html has other `href` it wont work because it can't see the `div` with `id="main"` , so my question how would I get the `div` of the index and reload it , or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: home.html has other href ????????what is the meaning..

Comment: Home.html is an other page with it's own href links.....what is not clear about it!?

Comment: You have jquery as one of your tags and you say that you are using it but I don't see where you are using it in your example code. Anyway, is what you are trying to say is content retrieved via ajax and placed in the main div does not render links?

Comment: yeah kinda thing I have changed the codes to be


`....
if (req) {
        req.open('GET', url, false);
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                element.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        req.send(null);
        //element.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    } 
.....`
now it render the links , but it doesn't clear the old content , it adds the new content on the old